# Dynamic creation of layout and swapping them in android

Tags: android

I want a create a quiz app in android in which I want to dynamically change the questions for every 60 seconds in the same layout where the number of question vary dynamically.

I planned to do a quiz system which creates layout dynamically and changes it between some interval.

I tried with a countdown Timer but it's not accurate.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_student_main);

    String[] fr={"National Bird Of India?","How is your life?","What's yourFavourite dish","Whats your hobby","Whats your skin color"};
String s="";
int i;

    i=0;
    int seconds=10000;

    CountDownTimer countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer((fr.length*seconds)+seconds, seconds)
    {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long l)
            {

                String s = String.valueOf(l);
                char[] f = s.toCharArray();
                textView.setText(String.valueOf(i+1));
                textView2.setText(fr[i]);
                if(!s.equals(String.valueOf(f[0])))
                {
                    textView2.setText(fr[i]);
                    i++;
                }
                else
                {
                    s=String.valueOf(f[0]);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onFinish()
            {
                Intent intent=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Finish_quiz.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
        };
        countDownTimer.start();
}
```

Comment: your question is not clear.What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want a create a quiz app in android in that I want to dynamically change the questions for every 60 seconds in same layout where number of Questions is also dynamic which can vary..

Comment: do you want to change the order of questions, is that your question?

Comment: Please explain what's the problem with your code, what did you try and what didn't work.

Comment: No, I want to change the questions something like view flipper with a flip interval of 60 seconds. So in between the interval of each 60 seconds, i want to go to next question

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague but looks like fragments are what you need. Assuming you know about Fragments in Android, they are designed for the exact purpose of changing your UI look and feel on the go within the same container (which in Android terminology is the `Activity` component).

So consider you have 50 questions and all of them roughly falls under 5 segments requiring you to design 5 different layouts. So what you do is define 5 different fragments with their distinct look and feel. Albeit you can always reuse individual UI components among fragments which is what you should do, thus requiring you to write lesser code.

Now when you want to display a different UI for the next question, you can just replace the current fragment in the UI. For performance sake, you can create instance of all the 5 fragments type in your activity start and just go on replacing the current viewable fragment.

Please read upon - https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html

Comment: Okay, i got your answer. I will create with fragments but I want to know how to change the fragment after 60 seconds

Comment: If you are new to the concept of fragments, you should read upon this link - https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html.  Don't use a timer, they are kind of CPU intensive. Instead use `Handlers` to post a message on the UI thread after each 60 seconds. Read upon this link which explains this -https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html